# runOnUiThread() method for Android

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm used to calling runOnUiThread() to ensure that a block of code gets run, well, on the UI thread.  I would like the same ease to launch a block of code *off* the UI thread.  What should that method look like?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suppose you would say the method is `start()`:

```
new Thread() {
  public void run() {
    // do something
  }
}.start();
```

or use `AsyncTask` or some `Executor` from `java.util.concurrent` or whatever.

Comment: Ah got there 30 seconds before me, a capital D in it haha

Answer (score 3):

You most likely want an `AsyncTask`. Refer to this article: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to ASyncTask

```
    new Thread(){
        public void run() {
            // Do something
        };
    }.start();
```